# OGRFeature setting multiple fields

Tags: c++, qt

Hi all to start off with:

Using Gdal compiled with Xerces

Coding in C++ with the QT Creator version 5.4.1

So my problem is im trying to use Gdal to create my own Esri shapefile, I get a strange runtime error when trying to add multiple fields

Example:

```
    // Create a ogr feeature
    OGRFeature* ogr_feature;
    // Set a bunch of fields
    ogr_feature->SetField("Blah","Blah");
    ogr_feature->SetField("Foo","Foo");
    ogr_feature->SetField("Bar","Bar");
    ogr_feature->SetField("Test","Test");
```

When I run the program once it hits this part it gives out this error message:

Error :1 Invalid Index -1

I'm not too sure what's causing this. I've tried taking out all but 1 and thats fine doesnt give me any errors. But more than 1 it throws that error.

Anyone know how to fix this/ why its doing it?

Comment: Is that literally the code you're using? If so, `ogr_feature` is an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: Just a shortened down version, I've fixed it now anyways. Will post the answer